# Why is conjunctive normal form (CNF) "better" for SAT than disjunctive normal form (DNF)?

Tags: satisfiability, boolean-algebra

When hand-manipulating algebra DNF (sum of products) is easier than
CNF (product of sums). Possibly because factoring is more difficult
than expanding. So why is it the opposite for computational boolean
algebra?

Perhaps one argument is that in CNF one can show that an expression is
false by showing that one clause is false. But that is no different
from showing that an expression is true by showing that one
conjunction is true.

Comment: I suppose if we want to prove something can be true, CNF allows us to eliminate big swaths of the solution space, while DNF would do the same if we wanted to prove something can be false, but that's not what we want to prove

Answer (score 2):

One (serious) issue is that converting to DNF is *harder* than solving the SAT problem itself! E.g. you can see that:

$$  x\wedge y\ \vee\ x\wedge \neg z$$

has 2 solutions, $x=\top,\ y=\top$ and $x=\top,\ z=\bot$, without doing any fancy work.

This means that converting into DNF is going to be tough, as opposed to CNF for which there are [efficient algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation). Note that in the CNF conversion, the result is not strictly *equivalent* but merely *equisatisfiable*, which is all that SAT solvers care about.

Comment: You just expand the expression and you get the DNF. I don't understand why that is tough or not possible  to do in linear time.

Comment: Try to expand $(A\vee B)\wedge (C\vee D)\wedge (E\vee F)$!

Comment: It wasn't difficult, though the expanded expression is longer of course.

Comment: How *much* larger?